# Using a different controller for GET and POST in Laravel but using the same name

Tags: php, laravel, url-routing, laravel-5.1, laravel-routing

I am writing route and controller rules for a web application. In a number of rules, a problem has emerged, which is that I need to match both GET and POST verbs, and send them to the controller, but different methods.

I considered using `Route::controller('tracking', 'TrackingController')` for this, but then it requires different names for each internal route, whereas I want to specify one name for both. Besides, I've read nothing but negativity regarding the usage, suggesting that it is not a good idea.

Here's what I have currently:

```
Route::match(['get', 'post'], '/tracking', [
    'as' => 'tracking',
    'uses' => 'TrackingController@index'
]);
```

While implementing this, I have discovered that I need to have two controller methods, `index` and `track`. How can I efficiently route `GET` to `index` and `POST` to `track`, while maintaining the same controller (`TrackingController`) and the same name (`tracking`)?

I considered using two separate routes, e.g. `Route::get` and `Route::post`, but that doesn't feel very eloquent.

Comment: Actually having `Route::get` and `Route::post` is very eloquent way, very readable and very easy to understand to whoever is going to maintain that application because is self-documenting. You might consider route grouping if you really want to do something about it, but you will still end up with two routes, `get` and `post`

Comment: @GladToHelp What about the route naming? Should I just name one of them, when there's two identical routes? After all, it's just for reverse routing.

Comment: I think it's always good to name both of them and then use the route name accross the project to generate links, because it makes your application simple to maintain. Imagine you want to change the uri later at some point, it would be much much easier when you only have to do it in your routes.php instead of doing a search in your entire project.

Comment: @GladToHelp Righto, I've done that now and it seems to work as I want it. I'd not really considered that naming them both would be easier. Now I've named the GET `tracking` and the POST `tracking.track`, meaning that I can then change them later safely should I need to.

Answer (score 1):

you can use easily Route Controller,like this

```
Route::controller('tracking', 'TrackingController')
```

In here if you wanna use same method for both get and post,just use **any** prefix in method,like

```
//for both get and post
public function anyUrl();
//only get
public function getUrl();
//only post
public function postUrl();
```

Or use

```
Route::any('/url', function () {
return 'Hello World';
});
```